# How does an add-in for SCCM get the commandline parameter?

Tags: sccm

I am troubleshooting an in-house PowerShell script (compiled in PowerShell Studio) that is used to schedule distributing SCCM package content to our DPs (SCCM 2012). The script has a parameter for $Commandline that it gets when I right-click on a package and run this utility. What I am unable to determine is how the packageid is getting passed to the add-in? I am woefully inexperienced in regard to creating add-ins for SCCM, so this may be a very basic question. Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it is a little hard to tell depending on how this add-in was built. The classic way to build a console extension would be to create an XML file in a subfolder of your console installation.

```
<SCCMConsolePath>\XmlStorage\Extensions\Actions
```

The folders there have GUIDs that correspond to the nodes of the console. If this is the only addin there is hopefully only one subfolder. If there are several my best guess would be that since it expands packages it is `3ad39fd0-efd6-11d0-bdcf-00a0c909fdd7`, if this is also not true you have to go into each folder and check each xml file manually.

The XML Files inside would be pretty easy to read looking roughly likes this

```
<ActionDescription Class="Executable" DisplayName="xxxx" MnemonicDisplayName="xxxxx" Description = "xxxxx">    <ShowOn>      <string>DefaultContextualTab</string> <!-- RIBBON -->     <string>ContextMenu</string> <!-- Context Menu -->   </ShowOn>       <Executable>
  <FilePath>"xxxxxx"</FilePath>
  <Parameters>"##SUB:PackageID##" "##SUB:Name##"</Parameters>
 </Executable>
 <ImagesDescription>
   <ResourceAssembly>
     <Assembly>AdminUI.UIResources.dll</Assembly>
     <Type>Microsoft.ConfigurationManagement.AdminConsole.UIResources.Properties.Resources.resources</Type>
   </ResourceAssembly>
   <ImageResourceName>CreateProgram</ImageResourceName>
 </ImagesDescription>
</ActionDescription>
```

Parameters in this case is the way the PackageID is passed namely ##SUB:PackageID## which is name of this specific parameter within the node `3ad39fd0-efd6-11d0-bdcf-00a0c909fdd7`. Unfortunately to me it seems as if this is not a basic question at all, meaning there is absolutely no great documentation for how these things work. I wouldn't even know how you could get a list of all possible parameters in all nodes.